# Spring boot controller not redirecting correctly

Tags: forms, spring-boot, redirect, controller, thymeleaf

I am experiencing a problem with the redirect of the method below in my controller class.

**When I click on the submit button it does not redirect me to http://localhost:8080/manager/customers but it redirects to http://localhost:8080/customer/1/manager/customers**

*Note: the 1 is the customer id that I choose to add orders to*

Am I doing something wrong??

```
@PostMapping(value = "/customer/{id}/orders")
    public String projectAddOrders(@PathVariable("id") Long customerId, @RequestParam Long orderId, Model model) {
        Order order = orderService.findOrderById(orderId);
        Customer customer = customerService.findCustomerById(customerId);

        if (customer != null) {
            if (!customer .hasOrder(order)) {
                customer .getOrders().add(order);
            }
            customerService.saveCustomer(customer );
            model.addAttribute("customer", customerService.findCustomerById(customer Id));
            model.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getAllOrders());
            return "redirect:manager/customers";
        }
        return "redirect:manager/customers";
    }
```

This is the HTML from:

```
<form th:action="@{/customer/{id}/orders(id=${customer.id})}" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          Customer name: <b th:text="${customer.name}" /><br/>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">       
         Customer orders:
            <b><span th:each="order, iterStat : ${customer.orders}">
                <span th:text="${order.name}"/><th:block th:if="${!iterStat.last}">,</th:block>
            </span></b>
        </div>      
    </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="user">Add Order</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        <select name="orderId">
            <option th:each="order: ${orders}" 
                th:value="${order.id}" 
                th:text="${order.name}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Order">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning

```
return "redirect:manager/customers";
```

into

```
return "redirect:/manager/customers";
```

Mind the slash between 'redirect:' and 'manager'.
Does it work?

Comment: No, still doesn't work. I noticed that it does this with every method with has and {id} in it's  @RequestMapping

Comment: Does it add the order correctly? Also, it would help to see your class level request mapping (before public class...) and manager/customer @GetMapping.

Comment: yes it adds the order correctly. I don't have a mapping at class level. @GetMapping(value = "manager/customers")
 public String getAllCustomersForManager(Model model) {
  //do stuff
  return "manager/customers";
 }

Comment: Really, try to add the slash "\" before "manager\customers". Without it, you will redirect to your previous URI + the new one, that is, http://localhost:8080/customer/1/manager/customers, which you do not want.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying and I guess you're right, I read it somewhere as well. But it's not working either way so I'm not sure

Comment: I see. Sorry, can't thing of much right now. Now, I'm being pedantic here, but hope you have tried to add the slash in your first redirect and not only the last.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding

```
registry.addViewController("**/manager/customers").setViewName("redirect:/manager/customers");
```

in my **ApplicationWebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer** class